# git svn error after change the svn repo address

Tags: git, git-svn

I cloned a repo using `git svn -s clone` first from

```
svn+ssh://savannah.psi.ch/afs/psi.ch/project/meg/svn/elog
```

But the repo laterly has been changed to

```
svn+ssh://svn@savannah.psi.ch/repos/meg/elog
```

Then I edit the `.git/config` file, just change the line below `[remote-svn "svn"]`. Then `git svn fetch` works fine, but any other `svn` commands, such as `svn info`, `svn rebase`, fail in the error:

> Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history

I searched stack overflow, someone got the same error before, but the answer does not work for me. What should I do after changing the svn-repo address?

Platform: archlinux; git: 1.7.7.3; svn: 1.6.17

Answer (score 5):

I came here via looking for revmap issues when using this solution but it gets the rebasing / fetching working:

http://honk.sigxcpu.org/con/Using_git_svn_when_upstream_moves_the_subversion_repository.html

```
git config svn-remote.svn.url newUrl
git config svn-remote.svn.rewriteRoot originalUrl
git svn rebase
```

revmaps don't seem to be used correctly for merges, not sure if tags will work either yet...

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting just the .metadata file and run `git svn fetch` as if this was right after a fresh `git svn init`

Another idea would be something as described at: http://ciaran-lee.com/2008/06/13/how-to-fix-git-svn-if-the-svn-repo-moves.html

Comment: I delete `.git/svn/.metadata`, then `git svn fetch`. The error is still there. Thanks any way.

Comment: Hmm, if this were a regular git repo, it would be possible to add the new repo location as a separate remote. Also, it seems that error can occur as a result of multiple causes.